# Drawing a Complicated Function Graph With Pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, graphs

I am trying to draw 2 somewhat complicated graphs with `pgfplots` but having a hard time. The first graph I am trying to draw is this graph:

[image]

Desmos version of it is available [here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/2bwoqrosug)

Issue with this is when I do `\addplot[thick, black, samples=200, domain=0:2]{6 x + 2 y <= 19};` (for example) `pgfplots` does not like the fact that I have `y` in my equation. I have no idea how can I circumvent this or fix this as I really couldn't find any posts about this.

```tex
\begin{axis}[axis lines=center,
  xlabel=$x_{1}$,
  ylabel=$x_{2}$,
  xmin=-1,
  xmax=4.5,
  ymin=-1,
  ymax=5.5,
  xtick distance=1,
  ytick distance=1,
  clip=false,]
  \addplot[name path=A, thick, black, samples=200, domain=0:4]{6 x + 2 y <= 19};
  \addplot[name path=B, thick, black, samples=200, domain=0:4]{2 x + 3 y <= 13};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The other graph I've been attempting to draw is this:

[image]

Issue here is that I am unsure how to draw such a graph where the x and y axis deal with fractions like `\frac{13}{3}` or `\frac{13}{4}` etc.

I'd really appreciate any guidance I can get regarding these 2 graphs. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since you are not new here at TeX.SX you should already know that it really helps when you add an MWE or also a minimal *not* working example. Then we -- the helpers -- don't need to do *everything*, but can concentrate on solving your question.

Comment: Searching for [`[pgfplots] inequality`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bpgfplots%5D+inequality) here on TeX.SX gives several results that should be more than enough to solve your problem. Therefore I tend to close the question as duplicate.

Comment: @StefanPinnow I am aware but I saw no purpose of posting a code that doesn't work. I've attached it now, but the code doesn't work as I stated. I'll also take a look at the search query you posted, appreciated.

Comment: Also the issue with the post that is above this post (i.e duplicate of) is that it still deals with `y` on the other side of the equation. So it's `y \ge x + 5` instead of `6x + 8y \le 11` for example. I'll still give it a read, but yeah.

Comment: Thank you for your understanding. In the unlikely case you shouldn't find the solution you are of course free to state it here. And if you find a more suitable "duplicate link" I'll be happy to change it. Good luck!!